# Linq-to-sql Not Contains or Not in?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I'm building a poll widget. I've 2 tables, call them Polls and PollsCompleted. I need to do a linq query to get all the Polls that do not exist for a given user in PollsCompleted.

I have the following sets:

For Polls
Where Active == True

For PollsCompleted
Where UserId == ThisUserId
Where PollId = Polls.Id

Now I need to get all Polls that do not exist in PollsCompleted. I need an example for this using either a single or multiple queries. I've tried to break it down into 2 queries.

Basically, I've 2 IQueryables of type T and T1. I want to take all T's where T.ID does not exist in T1.ParentId.

Comment: Do you know that you can apply the "!" operator to .Contains()?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
T.Where(x => ! T1.Select(y => y.ParentID).Contains(x.ID))
```

In Linq you often work from the bottom up.  Here we first get a collection of all the parentIDs in T1 -- the T1.Select(...) part.   Then we create a where clause that selects all of the Ts whose IDs are not contained in that set.

Note that the result is a query.  To materialize it, use ToList() or similar on the statement above.

Answer (score 6):

Use `Except`. That will work in this case.

For your reference [Enumerable.Except Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx)