# Converting LINQ to Entity stement with not contains into a Lambda expression

Tags: lambda, linq-to-entities

I have three entities as shown below.

```
Student { StudentID, Name, Age } 

Parent { ParentID, Name, Age } 

StudentParent { StudentParentID, StudentID, ParentID }
```

I need to get an IQueryable list of students that are a certain age and have no parents. I am currently using the following code which does work.

```
IQueryable<Student> Student s = from s in db.Students
                                 where s.Age == 18
                                 where !(from sp in db.StudentParent where sp.StudentID == s.StudentID select sp.StudentID).Contains(s.StudentID)
                                 select s;
```

I would just like help converting this to a Lambda expression.

Comment: There was a similar question that was asked a bit ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739246/linq-to-sql-not-contains-or-not-in. The answer is a bit more concise than the answers so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
db.Students.Where( s =>
    s.Age == 18 &&  db.StudentParent.All(sp => sp.StudentID != s.StudentID)
);
```

Edit: This assumes that you do not have a link from students to parents; if you do, use it instead of a join for better readability.

Comment: this worked   and I only made on small change      Thanks again              db.Students.Where( s =>
    s.Age == 18 &&  s.StudentParent.All(sp => sp.StudentID != s.StudentID)
);

Answer (score 4):

You should create an association in your entity model.

You can then write

```
db.Students.Where(s => s.Age == 18 && s.Parents.Count == 0)
```

You should never need to explicitly query a join table (such as your `StudentParent`) when using an ORM.