# Sql query in this scenario - C#

Tags: sql, c#-4.0

I have Names table:

```
ID           Name 
1            Ken
2            John
3            Tom
```

...

I have following variable in c# code:
`var names`; //which is list of some names like "ken, Tom"

I need a query that goes through Names table and gets all names that are not in names variable.

So in above case if i run a query result should be John.

I am not sure how to write a query in this problem i am iterating through names and running query again and again and i think this is really bad way to do it. Can someone please suggest what is most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Have you looked at the SQL "IN" statement?  It seems like your best option, but do your due dilligence and be sure you're validating that the names variable contains nothing that can be used for SQL Injection.  (One simple way to test is to include the name "O'Reilley").  More info:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx and  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

Comment: Are you using Lync? Post your code.

Comment: @DavidStratton - How can i use "in" here?                      Select * from Names where Name <> "Ken"

Comment: Is `var names` a collection of some kind (array, list, etc) or a comma delimited string (as `"ken, Tom"` may suggest)?

Comment: WHERE NOT [Names] IN ('Ken', 'Tom')

Comment: @DavidStratton - Exactly what i was looking for thanks! If you write this line as an answer i will mark it as an answer. Thanks again!

Comment: @user15741 gave this exact answer...

Comment: Give it to @user15741 - I don't need the points.  Again, please just be sure to sanitize the input to be sure it's protected from SQL Injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to do it in T-SQL, you could do something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE Name NOT IN (<<comma separated list of values here>>)
```

That could be done inline or in a stored procedure.

If you can use Entity Framework (you indicate .Net 4.0, so you should be able to), then you can use something similar to this answer:

[Linq-to-sql Not Contains or Not in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739246/linq-to-sql-not-contains-or-not-in)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [table-valued parameter](http://orionseven.com/blog/2009/09/30/using-table-valued-parameters-in-sql-server-2008-and-c/) to send the data in.  At that point, you can compare normally.

Answer (score 0):

If the table is as simple as you have shown, then I cannot imagine it having more than a couple of thousand records. That being the case, a table scan should be an acceptable solution.

```
select Name
  from tbl
 where ', ' + @names + ', ' not like '%, ' + name + ', %';
```

Parameterize the @names variable.